# Configuring gradle plugin from build script

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a gradle build script which uses a [binary plugin](https://github.com/craigburke/karma-gradle), and this plugin in turn uses [another plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin). I need to change one of the [configuration values](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md#configuring-the-plugin) used by the second plugin - I can't simply edit the configuration of this plugin manually, because it is downloaded at build time. I am looking for a way to specify the configuration value from my top-level build script, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `karma-gradle` plugin, the `node` plugin is applied [like that](https://github.com/craigburke/karma-gradle/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/craigburke/gradle/KarmaPlugin.groovy#L121) :

```
private static void setupNode(Project project) {
    project.plugins.apply NodePlugin
    NodeExtension nodeConfig = project.extensions.findByName('node') as NodeExtension
    nodeConfig.download = true
    nodeConfig.version = DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION
}
```

So you can simply set all the needed properties in a `node` block in your build script, as it's read from the `project`.

```
node {
    // Version of node to use.
    version = '0.11.10'

    // Version of npm to use.
    npmVersion = '2.1.5'

    // ...
}
```